# Lista dentro de un for in

Tags: javascript, variables, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
    for (a in secciones){
            ncompoa += "<h1>";
            ncompoa += secciones[a];
            ncompoa += "</h1>";
            ncompoa += "<ol>";

            for (li in producto) {
            if (producto[li].grupo == secciones[a]) 
            {
                  ncompoa += "<li>";
                  ncompoa += producto[li].n;
                  ncompoa += "</li>";
             }
        }       
            };
ncompoa += "</ol>";
    document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = ncompoa;
```

Que me da como resultado lo siguiente:

TITULO1

1. Contenido
2. Contenido
3. Contenido

   TITULO2

   1. Contenido
   2. Contenido
   3. Contenido

      TITULO3

      1. Contenido
      2. Contenido
      3. Contenido

Y el resultado que deseo es que sea:

TITULO1

1. Contenido
2. Contenido
3. Contenido

TITULO2

1. Contenido
2. Contenido
3. Contenido

TITULO3

1. Contenido
2. Contenido
3. Contenido

Puede alguien orientarme que debo hacer o donde debo colocar el

```
ncompoa += "<ol>";
```

para que esa etiqueta quede excluida del primer for..?

Comment: Hola Jose M. recuerda que los navegadores por defecto cierran etiquetas dónde ellos creen que deben cerrarse (en caso de no encontrar una etiqueta de cierre), en este caso como en cada iteración abres una etiqueta <ol> pero esa nunca la cierras, en navegador la cierra por defecto después del último item de cada iteración, si trabajas con elementos dinámicos te recomiendo primeramente hacer una prueba en html simulando lo que haría tu script y así evitar estos tipos de inconsistencias. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, muy amable..! Si en efecto no lograba ver que la etiqueta no la estaba cerrando el ciclo for si no el navegador..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes cerrar la etiqueta `<ol>` después de tu segundo `for`:

```
for (a in secciones) {

  ncompoa += "<h1>";
  ncompoa += secciones[a];
  ncompoa += "</h1>";
  ncompoa += "<ol>";

  for (li in productos) {
    if (productos[li].grupo == secciones[a]) {
      ncompoa += "<li>";
      ncompoa += productos[li].n;
      ncompoa += "</li>";
    }
  }

  // Aquí debes cerrar la etiqueta
  ncompoa += "</ol>";

};
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
var secciones = ["TITULO1", "TITULO2", "TITULO3"];
var productos = [{
    "n": "Producto1",
    "grupo": "TITULO1"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto2",
    "grupo": "TITULO1"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto3",
    "grupo": "TITULO1"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto4",
    "grupo": "TITULO2"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto5",
    "grupo": "TITULO2"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto6",
    "grupo": "TITULO2"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto7",
    "grupo": "TITULO3"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto8",
    "grupo": "TITULO3"
  },
  {
    "n": "Producto9",
    "grupo": "TITULO3"
  },
];

var ncompoa = "";

for (a in secciones) {

  ncompoa += "<h1>";
  ncompoa += secciones[a];
  ncompoa += "</h1>";
  ncompoa += "<ol>";

  for (li in productos) {
    if (productos[li].grupo == secciones[a]) {
      ncompoa += "<li>";
      ncompoa += productos[li].n;
      ncompoa += "</li>";
    }
  }

  // Aquí debes cerrar la etiqueta
  ncompoa += "</ol>";

};
document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = ncompoa;
```

```html
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes cerrar la etiqueta  `ncompoa += "</ol>";`  dentro del primer bucle

```js
var secciones = ['colores','letras'];
var producto = [{grupo: 'colores',n:'azul'},{grupo: 'colores',n:'rojo'},
{grupo: 'letras',n:'A'},{grupo: 'letras',n:'B'}];

var ncompoa = "";
   for (a in secciones){
            ncompoa += "<h1>";
            ncompoa += secciones[a];
            ncompoa += "</h1>";
            ncompoa += "<ol>";

            for (li in producto) {
            if (producto[li].grupo == secciones[a]) 
            {
                  ncompoa += "<li>";
                  ncompoa += producto[li].n;
                  ncompoa += "</li>";
             }
        }       
        ncompoa += "</ol>";
            };

    document.getElementById('contenido').innerHTML = ncompoa;
```

```html
<div id="contenido"></div>
```